# Copy a file by ANT from a folder in workspace to a folder in the project

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have a file which i need to copy from workspace/dir1 to the current project[workspace/dir2]

My ANT build file is in dir2

Comment: what did you try ? did you check http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you reviewed the [ant tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html) that are available to you?

The [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) can be used to do this:

```
<copy file="../dir1/filename" todir="."/>
```

The copy will only happen if the file doesn't already exist in the project directory, or if the file in `../dir1` is newer than the extant copy in the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to copy workspace

```
<project name="ant_workspace_demo">
    <target name="copy_workspace">
        <copy todir="../New_files">
            <fileset dir="AntWorkspace"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Then, in command prompt(windows) enter "ant copy_workspace".